# Odd crash in lwjgl

Tags: java, crash, lwjgl

So my game has started having a really odd error. It keeps crashing as if there was a `System.exit(0)` was there, but I am tracking it and it just suddenly dies.
Here is what happens in the Main

```
    Loader loader = new Loader();

    Model.init(loader);

    System.out.println(1);
    MasterRenderer renderer = new MasterRenderer(loader);
    System.out.println(2);
```

Here `1` is printed out but not `2`, so I figured it must be something in `MasterRenderer`

```
public MasterRenderer(Loader loader){
    System.out.println(3);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);
    createProjectionMatrix();
    renderer = new EntityRenderer(shader,projectionMatrix);
    terrainRenderer = new TerrainRenderer(terrainShader,projectionMatrix);
    skyboxRenderer = new SkyboxRenderer(loader, projectionMatrix);
}
```

But not even `3` is being printed out. I cannot see why it is suddenly crashes as there is no errors. Does anyone see why? I'm not sure what code to give, but if one of you could ask I will give it as I have no clue what is happening.

Comment: What class does MasterRenderer extend? What code is in the constructor of that class?

Comment: MasterRenderer does not extend any class.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the problematic code with your debugger?

Comment: Thats the thing there isn't any. The debugger will only say that it was terminated with exit code -1, but I don't see how as no code is even being ran.

Comment: Is this the first reference to MasterRenderer? Do you have a custom classloader?

Comment: Yes this is the first reference. The only thing before it is me initializing the Loader and creating the Display.

Comment: Is this code called from within a try/catch block?

Comment: No it is not using any try/catch blocks anywhere

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in between when I call MasterRenderer and `System.out.println(2)` which is in the first line of the contructer, but it is crashing.